# Copying python script from GitHub to Azure virtual machine

Tags: python, azure-devops, windows-task-scheduler

In the Azure virtual machine, I'm running a Python script (xyz.py) through the Windows task scheduler.
Every time a developer commits a new change to the file, it needs to be deployed automatically.

In order for the task scheduler to pick a newer version of the script, I want to deploy the script on a virtual machine using the Azure DevOps "copy task.".

Is there a better way of deploying a single file from GitHub to an AZ-virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install a build agent to your target system and configure a new build to download sources and run a script: [Build GitHub repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), [Python Script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/python-script?view=azure-devops)
2. You can download your script directly from GitHub through Rest API. PowerShell example to download a file:

   ```
   $user = "<user>"
   $token = "<pat>" #https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

   $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

   $filename = "c:/temp/<targetfile.ext>"
   $gitfilepath = "https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/contents/<file_path>"

   function InvokeGetRequest ($PostUrl)
   {   
       return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
   }

   $answ = InvokeGetRequest $gitfilepath

   $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($answ.content)
   [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)
   ```